# Blank nodes in class definition for enforcing identity

Tags: logic, semantic-web, owl

I hope the question is not trivial, I spent a decent amount of time looking for an answer around.
 I am creating an ontology in OWL and I've been trying to enforce a particular constraint into a class description but not being able to do it with the tools provided by OWL and resorted to blank nodes as existential variables in the description of the class. Protege5 did not like it a bit.
 I'd like to model classes of spaces and movements from one space to another, and in particular I'd like to model a movement that has as a target the same space as the starting space.
 In logic I'd describe my InternalMovement class as:

```
InternalMovement = forall ?x exist ?y (Movement(?x) ^ space(?x,?y) ^ direction(?x,?y))
```

In OWL variables do not exist and enforcing the identity of a blank nodes throughout a class description doesn't seem possible. I resorted to blank nodes because they should be treated as existential variables and I hope using blank nodes ids would do the trick. I was wrong and I don't know how to model this simple class.
 The Turtle snippet is this:

```
:Movement rdf:type owl:Class .
:Space rdf:type owl:Class .

:direction rdf:type owl:FunctionalProperty ,
     owl:ObjectProperty ;
     rdfs:domain :Movement ;
     rdfs:range :Space .

:space rdf:type owl:FunctionalProperty ,
     owl:ObjectProperty ;
     rdfs:domain :Movement ;
     rdfs:range :Space .

:InternalMovement rdf:type owl:Class ;
    owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Class ;
       owl:intersectionOf ( :Movement
          [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
            owl:onProperty :space ;
            owl:hasValue _:sp1
          ]
          [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
            owl:onProperty :target ;
            owl:hasValue _:sp1
          ]
        )
 ] .
```

I would expect that the following individual would be classified as InternalMovement, but obviously it doesn't.

```
:internalmovement rdf:type :Movement ,
  :space :room1 ;
  :direction :room1 .

:room1 rdf:type :Space.
```

Can anyone help me, please?
 Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand your pseudo-definition: `InternalMovement = forall ?x exist ?y (Movement(?x) ^ space(?x,?y) ^ direction(?x,?y))`.   A class expression should be, essentially a one-place predicate.  E.g., `Man(?x) = Male(?x) & Person(?x)`.  Do you mean `InternalMovement(?x) = Movement(?x) & exist ?y (space(?x,?y) ^ direction(?x,?y))` where Movement is a class and space and direction are properties?  Unfortunately, OWL doesn't have property intersection;  if it did, you could say `exist ?y (space & direction)(?x,?y)`.

Comment: Hi @JoshuaTaylor, yes, I wanted to express the OWL class definition with fol formula. Unfortunately I'm rusty with both. But that is exactly what I wanted to describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to define a class by specifying that it has the same value for two particular properties.  If OWL supported property intersection (some description logics do), then you could write

> InternalMovement ≡ ∃(space ⊓ direction)

Unfortunately, OWL doesn't have this.  However, you could define a property that is a subproperty of both *space* and *target* and use that.  That is:

> spaceAndDirection ⊑ space
>   spaceAndDirection ⊑ target
>   InternalMovement ≡ ∃spaceAndDirection

This means that if x is an InternalMovement, then there exists a y such that spaceAndDirection(x,y), and then from the subproperty axioms, we may infer space(x,y) and direction(x,y).

That will take care of some of what you want, but not all of it.  If you just know that some movement x has some y as a space and as a direction, you still can't infer spaceAndDirection(x,y), and so you can't infer that x is an InternalMovement.

If you add cardinality axioms that a movement has exactly one space and exactly one direction, then you can ensure that if x has y as its space and direction, then *if* it has a spaceAndDirection value, then that value must be y.

If you also add the (min or exact) cardinality axiom that InternalMovement has (at least or exactly) one spaceAndDirection value, then if x is an InternalModement, then from any two of the following, you can infer the third:

1. space(x,y)

   - Since x is an InternalMovement, it must have a spaceAndDirection value. Call it z.  Then spaceAndDirection(x,z).  Then, since spaceAndDirection is a subproperty of space and direction, we also have space(x,z) and direction(x,z).  Since x is a Movement, it has exactly one space value, so y = z.  Then we also have direction(x,y) and spaceAndDirection(x,y).
2. direction(x,y)

   - Analogous to above.
3. spaceAndDirection(x,y)

   - Since spaceAndDirection is a subproperty of space and direction, we immediately have space(x,y) and direction(x,y).

Comment: Thanks. Than worked a treat! I just need to make this pattern flexible enough for property chains so that I can use it for general class definitions. Thank you :)

Comment: By the way, I tried to put the axioms to force space and direction to have cardinality of 1 but that didn't force the inference that if space and direction are the same y then the instance of Movement has spaceANDdirection y.

Comment: @gc3 Yes, I spoke a bit too quickly.  *If* a thing has the same space and direction, then *if* it also has a spaceAndDirection value, then the spaceAndDirection value must be the same.  The thing could just have *no* spaceAndDirection value at all.

Comment: The type of reasoning I'd want would be if there is a Movement(x) that has space(x,y) AND a  direction(x,y) then spaceAndDirection(x,y) therefore InternalMovement(x).

Comment: @gc3 well, you could add a subproperty axiom that "∃(space • inverse(direction)).Self ⊑ ∃ spaceAndDirection" so that is some x has some value y for both space and direction, then x has a spaceAndDirection property (which would then have to be y).  To make that existential work though, you might have to create a new property of which "space • inverse(direction)" is a subproperty.

Comment: Ok, I need to process that :D. Thanks a lot for the support. You've been very helpful.